# Difference of Sets

Tags: java

Hello everyone my question is a bit easy

```
public static Set<String> edits(String word) {
    Set<String> edits = new HashSet<String>();
    List<SplitWord> splits = SplitWord.allSplits(word);
    for (SplitWord split: splits) {
        String a = split.prefix;
        String b = split.suffix;
        int lb = b.length();
        if (lb > 0) {
            edits.add(a + b.substring(1)); // delete
            for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET.length(); ++i)
                edits.add(a + ALPHABET.charAt(i) + b.substring(1)); // replace
        }
        if (lb > 1)
            edits.add(a + b.charAt(1) + b.charAt(0) + b.substring(2)); // transpose
        for (int i = 0; i < ALPHABET.length(); ++i)
            edits.add(a + ALPHABET.charAt(i) + b); // insert
    }
    return edits;
}
public static Set<String> edits2(String word){//Double Edits according to norvig's spell corrector. Recursive way.
    Set<String> firstSet = new HashSet<String>();
    Set<String> secondSet= new HashSet<String>();

    firstSet.addAll(edits(word));
    for(String w: editsn){
            secondSet.addAll(edits(w));
            if(secondSet.contains(edits1(word))){
                secondSet.remove(w);
            }
    }

    return secondSet;
}
```

Here are my two methods, my "edits" method check spelling error for just one spell error. For example, if you write (atson) it says (watson). I use "edits" function in recursive way to check double spell errors(tson to watson for example). It works but my secondSet contains firstSet so it prints also one spelling errors too. I try to remove elements, but it doesn't work. So how can print the difference of two set?
(Mathematically A-B)

Comment: [`set1.removeAll(set2)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll%28java.util.Collection%29)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this method of set for the difference of two sets

[removeAll(java.util.Collection)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Set.html#removeAll(java.util.Collection))

Important Note : This mutates the set that you call `removeAll` on

Comment: I might add the (perhaps obvious) caveat that this mutates the set that you call `removeAll` on, so you should take a copy first if you need the contents after...

Comment: Depending on the _direction_ of the difference, you might need to call this both ways around (i.e. items in `a` and not in `b`, items in `b` not in `a`).

Answer (score 1):

Example:

Let's assume you have a `List` containing a some words;

```
// List declaration;
List<String> words = new ArrayList<String>();

// Populate list;
words.add("one");
words.add("two");
words.add("three");
```

And you have two sets;

```
// Set declaration; 
Set<String> setA = new HashSet<String>();
Set<String> setB = new HashSet<String>();
```

Let's populate both our sets with words from list we defined previously and add an exclusive word to one of the sets;

```
setA.addAll(words);
setB.addAll(words);
setA.add("four");
```

Now we want to remove those elements which are in both sets

```
setA.removeAll(setB);
```

Output the result:

```
System.out.println(setA);
```

Comment: What if we do a `setB.add("five")`?

Comment: @BoristheSpider `setB` would have another `String` added to it :)

Comment: But this is an element that is a "difference" - but in the opposite direction to that which you assume. This is two-way relationship; items in neither 'a' nor 'b', items in 'a' but not in 'b', items in 'b' but not in 'a', items in both 'a' and 'b'. You only look at items in `a` and not in `b` and not the reverse - that's my point.

Comment: @BoristheSpider difference between `setA` and `setB` can be established by calling method `removeAll` on the collection which needs to be checked agains't some arbitrary data. The common elements can also be extracted in a number of ways. For instance, use of method `containsAll(Collection<?> c)` could do the trick.

Answer (score 1):

It is also very easy to do with Guava, which most people have in their class path anyway.

```
final HashSet<String> set1 = Sets.newHashSet("A", "B");
final HashSet<String> set2 = Sets.newHashSet("B", "C");
final Sets.SetView<String> difference = Sets.difference(set1, set2); // contains A only
```